# Custom Designer form but no longer have Designer

Tags: custom-form, designer

A list was created in SharePoint 2007 with a custom form created in SharePoint Designer. The list has now been migrated to SharePoint 2013 and we don't have Designer, how do I remove the original custom form?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Designer 2013 can be downloaded free at [www.microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491)

Comment: This is for work and I don't have admin rights so I can't install designer

Comment: Try the following instead: On the List Settings page, select 'Form settings' under 'General Settings'. Change the Form Option from 'Modify the existing InfoPath form' to 'Use the default SharePoint form'. If you want to completely remove the form, also check 'Delete the InfoPath Form from the server'.

Comment: Hmm when I click Form Settings it says "Internet Explorer is required to use this feature." even though I am using Internet Explorer

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer Version 11